# JSON and ANDROID

Tags: android, json

I have a JSONArray:

myArray => [{"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"}, {"key3" : "value3", "key4" : "value4"}]

If I do
    myArray.get(1);
I get a Object.

I want the single keys and values of myArray[1]. How can I do this?
There is a way to have a HashMap that contains {"key3" : "value3", "key4" : "value4"} ?

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getJSONObject(1).getString("key3");` and put the returned value in your `HashMap`. I am not sure if there is an "automatic" way to do this.  You can look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `myArray.get()`, use `myArray.getJSONObject()` to return a `JSONObject`.  You can call `getString(key)`, `getDouble(key)`, `getInt(key)`, etc on the `JSONObject` to access the values.  See the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: wrong, because I can't use myArray.getJSONObject(1), eclipse says I can't cast Object to a JSONObject.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Assuming `myArray` is a `JSONArray`, are you saying that 

`JSONObject myObject = myArray.getJSONObject(1);` is invalid?